# Is there a Round Robin/Circular Queue available in Scala Collections

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-2.10

Is there a Round Robin Queue available in Scala Collections?

I need to repeatedly iterate a list that circles through itself

```
val x = new CircularList(1,2,3,4)
x.next (returns 1)
x.next (returns 2)
x.next (returns 3)
x.next (returns 4)
x.next (returns 1)
x.next (returns 2)
x.next (returns 3)
```

... and so on

Answer (score 54):

It's pretty easy to roll your own with `continually` and `flatten`:

```
scala> val circular = Iterator.continually(List(1, 2, 3, 4)).flatten
circular: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> circular.take(17).mkString(" ")
res0: String = 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

There's also a `continually` method on `Stream`—just be careful not to hold onto a reference to the head of the stream if you're going to be generating lots of elements.

Comment: This is a better answer as you are not holding up resources when compared to Stream

Comment: @Jatin good point, I edited my answer. I agree, this version is less error-prone.

Comment: I am unfortunately working with scala 2.9.2 :) and iterator is a part of 2.10 .. Is there a backward compatible version?

Comment: @user2780187: `Iterator`'s been around a long time—I just tested this code in 2.9.2 and it works as expected.

Comment: Note that `Stream.continually` doesn't make a circular structure (constant memory); it makes an endlessly repeating one (potentially unbounded memory use).

Comment: Why did that iterator return the last element first for take()?

Answer (score 12):

You can very easily create a circular list using a [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream).

```
scala> val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4).toStream
l: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> def b: Stream[Int] = l #::: b
b: Stream[Int]

scala> b.take(20).toList
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**Edit**: you want to make sure to define the repeated part beforehand, once and only once, to avoid blowing the heap (structural sharing in `Stream`). As in:

```
def circular[A](a: Seq[A]): Stream[A] = {
  val repeat = a.toStream
  def b: Stream[A] = repeat #::: b
  b
}
```

Comment: I am unfortunately working with scala 2.9.2 :) and iterator is a part of 2.10 .. Is there a backward compatible version?

Comment: Hum, I just tested, and both versions (`Stream` and `Iterator`) work fine in 2.9.2.

Comment: I would say that the solution provided by @TravisBrown is a better fit in this case, as `Iterator` provides a `next` method.

Answer (score 2):

Version more concentrated on getting new element on every execution.

```
val getNext: () => Int = {
  def b: Stream[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4).toStream #::: b
  var cyclicIterator: Stream[Int] = b
  () => {
    val tail = cyclicIterator.tail
    val result = tail.head
    cyclicIterator = tail
    result 
  }
} // could be written more sexy?
```

In your problem you can use it like:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10) yield getNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly in having an external mutable index, but it does do what's requested:

```
scala> var i = 0
scala> val ic4 = Iterator.continually { val next = IndexedSeq(1, 2, 3, 4)(i % 4); i += 1; next }
i: Int = 0
ic4: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> ic4 take 10 foreach { i => printf("ic4.next=%d%n", i) }
ic4.next=1
ic4.next=2
ic4.next=3
ic4.next=4
ic4.next=1
ic4.next=2
ic4.next=3
ic4.next=4
ic4.next=1
ic4.next=2
```

At least it illustrates `Iterator.continually`. There is also `Stream.continually`, which has the same signature.